# Magento 2: Billing address update not working when we use custom payment method to place order

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

We have implemented a custom payment method, but when anyone update the billing address in payment page of checkout , updated billing address is not reflecting after order got placed.

we used  $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote); to place an order and before placing an order we are updating the billing address as below.

```
 if (isset($billingAddress['firstname'])) {
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setFirstname($billingAddress['firstname']);
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setLastname($billingAddress['lastname']);
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setStreet($billingAddress['street']);
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setCity($billingAddress['city']);
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setTelephone($billingAddress['telephone']);
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPostcode($billingAddress['postcode']);
            if(!empty($billingAddress['region'])){
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegion($billingAddress['region']);
            }else{
                $billingAddress['region'] = '';
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegion($billingAddress['region']);

            }
            if (array_key_exists("regionId",$billingAddress))
            {
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegionId($billingAddress['regionId']);
            }else{
                $billingAddress['regionId'] = 'NULL';
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setRegionId($billingAddress['regionId']);

            }
            if (array_key_exists("saveInAddressBook",$billingAddress)){
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setSaveInAddressBook($billingAddress['saveInAddressBook']);
            }else{
                $billingAddress['saveInAddressBook'] = '0';
                $quote->getBillingAddress()->setSaveInAddressBook($billingAddress['saveInAddressBook']);
            }
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setCountryId($billingAddress['countryId']);
            $quote->save();
           
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have just updated the new address in quote. You need to catch the event when the payment is successful to update the new address on the order.